# Aggregation requires fun.aggregate: length used as default

Tags: r, reshape

I have a file that I would like to reshape it to use R: These are the commands that I am running.

```
x <- data.frame(read.table("total.txt", sep=",", header=T)
y <- melt(x, id=c("Hostname", "Date", "MetricType"))
```

when I issue this command to basically combine date with hour, I get an error and the window hangs.

```
yy <- cast(y, Hostname + Date + variable ~ MetricType)
```

This is the error:

```
Aggregation requires fun.aggregate: length used as default
       ServerNa Date       MetricType   Hour   Value
19502  server1 01/05/2012  MemoryAVG    Hour5  41.830000
19503  server1 01/05/2012 CPUMaximum    Hour5   9.000000
19504  server1 01/05/2012 CPUAVG+Sev    Hour5   9.060000
19505  server1 01/05/2012     CPUAVG    Hour5  30.460000
19506  server1 01/05/2012         61    Hour5  63.400000
19507  server1 01/05/2012         60    Hour5  59.300000
19508  server2 01/05/2012  MemoryAVG    Hour5  10.690000
19509  server2 01/05/2012 CPUMaximum    Hour5   1.000000
19510  server2 01/05/2012 CPUAVG+Sev    Hour5   0.080000
19511  server2 01/05/2012     CPUAVG    Hour5   1.350000
```

Is there an easy way to do this without hanging the server?

when I used library(reshape2) and this:

```
yy <- acast(y, Hostname + Date + variable ~ MetricType, fun.aggregate=mean)
```

all the values turn into NA. I have no clue what is going on?

Comment: There's a missing right-paren in the first line. (And) Which version of reshape?

Comment: `cast` has been replaced by `dcast` and `acast` in `reshape2`

Comment: I tried to use reshape2 and dcast and acast, not working values are becomeing NA. any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Clarification:** In the discussion below, I refer to `dcast()` rather than `cast()`. As Maiasaura notes in the comments, the function `cast()` from the `reshape` package has been replaced in the `reshape2` package by two functions: `dcast()` (for data.frame output) and `acast()` (for array or matrix output). In any case, my comments about the need for a `fun.aggregate` argument hold equally for `cast()`, `dcast()`, and `acast()`.

---

The error is being thrown because for at least one combination of the categorical variables in the call to `cast()`, your data.frame `y` must contain at least two rows of data. As documented in `?cast` (or `?dcast`):

> If the combination of variables you supply does not uniquely
>     identify one row in the original data set, you will need to supply
>     an aggregating function, ‘fun.aggregate’.

Run the code below to see how this works, and how it can be remedied. In the last line of code, I use the `fun.aggregate` argument to tell `dcast()` to use `mean()` to combine values for any repeated combination of variables. In its place, you can put whatever aggregation function best fits your own situation.

```
library(reshape2)

## A toy dataset, with one row for each combination of variables
d <- expand.grid(Hostname = letters[1:2],
                 Date = Sys.Date() + 0:1,
                 MetricType = LETTERS[3:4])
d$Value <- rnorm(seq_len(nrow(d)))

## A second dataset, in which one combination of variables is repeated
d2 <- rbind(d, d[1,])

## Runs without complaint
dcast(d, Hostname + Date ~ MetricType)

## Throws error asking for an aggregation function
dcast(d2, Hostname + Date ~ MetricType)

## Happy again, with a supplied aggregation function
dcast(d2, Hostname + Date ~ MetricType, fun.aggregate=mean)
```

Comment: cannot find dcast, I sued cast but it is still hanging:

Comment: I should have clarified: `cast()`, from the `reshape` package has been deprecated, and replaced by `dcast()` (when you want data.frame output) and `acast()` (when you want array or matrix output). To find `dcast`, you'll need to first do: `install.packages("reshape2"); library(reshape2)`. The bigger question, though, is whether you've tried supplying `cast()` with the name of a function in the `fun.aggregate` argument. It should work with `cast()` just as it does with the `dcast` and `acast` functions that have replaced it...

Comment: I have installed reshape2 already and tried it. when I use this  yy <- dcast(y, Hostname + Date + variable ~ MetricType, mean)
all the values become NA

Comment: Maybe try `fun.aggregate = function(X) mean(X, na.rm=TRUE)` instead of `fun.aggregate = mean`? Then, if that doesn't work, perhaps try `fun.aggregate = class` to see what is the class of the data that you are trying to take the mean of.

Comment: the same result, all values are NA

Comment: All right. This seems to be a second, and independent problem with your data. If you need help with it, you'll probably need to post (using `dput()`) some minimal subset of the data which reproduces the problem, ideally as a separate question. Best of luck.

Comment: fun.aggregate= class show they are characters, how do I make them numeric

Comment: I can't say without seeing your data. Are they character strings only containing digits? Are they factor levels? Do you know which column is being summarized? (In my example code, the output reports the column being used in each of the examples via the message "Using Value as value column".)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8713/discussion-between-mike-smith-and-josh-obrien)

Comment: can I send you this data. I really dont like to to use fun.aggregate function. Just so you know, I was able to do this on Windows platfrom using cast. The same set of commands does not work on linux.

Comment: Really interesting that you get different results using Windows and Linux on the same data. I can't help more on this (no time, sorry), but if you can create a small dataset that replicates the problem, you could post it as part of a new question and likely get help from others.